# School marks database with "mark categories"

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I'm trying to build a database to manage my school marks. Here in Germany we have different "categories". For example we have one category for all our written work and one for our tests. I want to have a defined number of "categories", each of them has its own list of marks. How do I have to design my database? I have tried the following:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Marks] (
    [Id] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [CategoryId] INT NOT NULL,
    [Name] NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
    [Value] DECIMAL(18,3) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE[dbo].[Categories] (
    [Id] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
    [Average] decimal(18,3) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE[dbo].[Subjects] (
    [Id] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
    [Teacher] NVARCHAR(MAX)  NOT NULL,
    [Average] decimal(18,3) NOT NULL,
    [TestsId] INT NOT NULL,
    [WrittenId] INT NOT NULL,
)
```

I come from C#, so I might not think like a SQL-Developer.

Comment: As far as what you've explained, this seems like it would work fine. Do you have any specific problems or do you just want validation of your design?

Comment: @LowlyDBA yes I wanted a validation of my design as a I don't have that much experience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marks are related to categories and subjects, so you need a SubjectId column in the Marks table so that you know what subject each record relates to.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Marks] (
    [Id] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [CategoryId] INT NOT NULL,
    [SubjectId] INT NOT NULL,
    [Name] NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
    [Value] DECIMAL(18,3) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE[dbo].[Categories] (
    [Id] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
    [Average] decimal(18,3) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE[dbo].[Subjects] (
    [Id] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
    [Teacher] NVARCHAR(MAX)  NOT NULL,
    [Average] decimal(18,3) NOT NULL,
)
```

It seems as if you were envisioning creating separate category records for every subject (i.e., you would have a tests category for writing, and a tests category for math), but you should just need one category of each type of category (tests, written, lab, etc.).  The categories get tied to the subjects by the marks table, which links to both of the other tables.

Comment: Just a note--I wouldn't bother with storing the averages in a table.  For a given student, there are only going to be a limited number of records, and you can calculate the average in a query.  If it were an average based on millions of rows, then yes, calculate once and store it, but not if it's just going to be a few dozen.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `Categories.Average` can be calculated from the data in the `Marks` table at any given time.

It is possible to set up (for example) a trigger to update `Categories.Average` any time a `Marks` rows is inserted, updated, or deleted.

That said, this does technically involve storing redundant data (since the average can be calculated whenever it's needed). Generally, you want to minimize redundant data, because when it's updated in one place, you have to always remember to update it (whether manually or automatically). Also, note that you'd have to work to prevent someone from manually updating the value in `Categories.Average`; since there's no way to adjust the multiple entries in `Marks` based on a change to `Average`, the calculated value and the stored value wouldn't match up.

If you have a strong reason to believe that you'll be needing to use the calculated `Average` far more often than you'll be adding, changing, or removing data, then it *may* make sense to store that calculated value.

Making sure that redundant data is left out of a data structure is generally referred to as *normalization*. The general rule when designing a data structure is to normalize it initially. It's often best to only *de-normalize* your data once you actually *confirm* that keeping it normalized is causing performance issues in some way.

Given your tables, to select the fields you've listed for `Categories` if you don't include the field `Average` in the table, you'd run this query:

```
SELECT cat.Id, cat.Name, AVG(Marks.Value) as Calc_Average
  FROM Categories cat
         LEFT OUTER JOIN Marks ON (cat.ID = Marks.CategoryId)
 GROUP BY cat.Id, cat.Name;
```

A `JOIN` generates a combination of rows from multiple tables - you have all the columns from each of the tables.

The `LEFT OUTER JOIN` tells SQL Server to bring back all the rows from `Categories` (or all rows matching your `WHERE` clause, if you wanted to add one). Each `Categories` row will be repeated for each matching row in `Marks`; however, if there are no matching rows, then the `Categories` row will be included in the result set, with all the fields that would have been picked up from the `Marks` table left blank.

Now, we don't want to see every row in `Marks` matched with the `Categories` rows (plus all the `Categories` rows that don't have any matches yet); we want to see each row in `Categories` once, with the average of all the `Marks` for that category. That's where the `GROUP BY` clause comes in. That says to pull all the rows with the same `Id` and `Name` from `Categories` together as a single row.

Then, the `AVG` function comes into play. That tells SQL Server to add up all the `Value` columns from the `Marks` rows attached to one row from `Categories`, and then take the average of that total.